# Python: predicate methods as properties?

Tags: python, pep8

By using the `@property` decorator, Python has completely eliminated the need for getters and setters on object properties (some might say 'attributes'). This makes code much simpler, while maintaining the extensibility when things do need to get more complex.

I was wondering what the Pythonic approach to the following kind of method is, though. Say I have the following class:

```
class A(object):
    def is_winner(self):
        return True  # typically a more arcane method to determine the answer
```

Such methods typically take no arguments, and have no side effects. One might call these predicates. And given their name, they often closely resemble something one might also have stored as a property.

I am inclined to add a `@property` decorator to the above, in order to be able to call it as an object property (i.e. `foo.is_winner`), but I was wondering if this is the standard thing to do. At first glance, I could not find any documentation on this subject. Is there a common standard for this situation?

Comment: If it makes your API *easier and cleaner to use*, then by all means, go for the `@property`! You don't need a style guide to tell you this.

Comment: Well, the first obvious change that has to be made in order to make it Pythonic is to stop camelcasing method names.

Comment: You may want to avoid making expensive methods (computation or I/O) into properties, at least if you're not memoizing them.

Comment: @райтфолд You're right. The reason it was camelcased is because it originated from a discussion that started as Java source code ;-)

Comment: @LukasGraf Is there a computational penalty to using properties over method calls? Or do you mean that it does not accurately reflect the underlying computation if presented as a property?

Comment: @Joost: there is no additional computational penalty, no.

Comment: @Joost: what Lukas does mean that attributes can give the impression of being instant and next-to-free to use; if the computation is expensive, you probably want to cache the outcome for repeated use.

Comment: personally I dislike the `@property` tag in general ... anything that obfuscates(even a little) is imho in general a bad idea (that said its a minor grievance and by all means use `@property` if you want)

Comment: @JoranBeasley properties have excellent use cases, especially when producing lazy attributes; calculating a value only when needed.

Comment: There's [`IOBase.closed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.closed), which…I _think_ is a `@property`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the general consensus is that attributes are generally seen as being instant and next-to-free to use, so if the computation being decorated as a @property is expensive, it's probably best to either cache the outcome for repeated use (@Martijn Pieters) or to leave it as a method, as methods are generally expected to take more time than attribute lookups. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance) notes specifically:

- Note 2: Try to keep the functional behavior side-effect free, although side-effects such as caching are generally fine.
- Note 3: Avoid using properties for computationally expensive operations; the attribute notation makes the caller believe that access is (relatively) cheap.

---

One particular use case of the @property decorator is to add some behavior to a class without requiring that users of the class change from `foo.bar` references to `foo.bar()` calls -- for example, if you wanted to count the number of times that an attribute was referenced, you could convert the attribute into a @property where the decorated method manipulates some state before returning the requested data.

Here is an example of the original class:

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# In user code
baxter = Cat('Baxter')
print(baxter.name)  # => Baxter
```

With the @property decorator, we can now add some under-the-hood machinery without affecting the user code:

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._name_access_count = 0

    @property
    def name(self):
        self._name_access_count += 1
        return self._name

# User code remains unchanged
baxter = Cat('Baxter')
print(baxter.name)  # => Baxter

# Also have information available about the number of times baxter's name was accessed
print(baxter._name_access_count)  # => 1
baxter.name                       # => 'Baxter'
print(baxter._name_access_count)  # => 2
```

This treatment of the @property decorator has been mentioned in some blog posts([1](http://blaag.haard.se/What-s-the-point-of-properties-in-Python/), [2](http://nipy.org/devel/guidelines/properties.html)) as one of the main use cases -- allowing us to initially write the simplest code possible, and then later on switch over to @propery-decorated methods when we need the functionality.